# Range validation in MVC Just shows Default Message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, model-view-controller, data-annotations

I'm totally confused about this ridiculous problem but I have to solve.
I have a field and I set required and range validation on it:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessage.InputDataStart + Field.SmtpPort + ValidationMessage.InputDataEnd)]        
[Range(FieldSize.PortNumberMin, FieldSize.PortNumberMax, ErrorMessage = ValidationMessage.InputDataIsOutOfRangeStart + Field.SmtpPort + ValidationMessage.InputDataIsOutOfRangeEnd)]
public int SmtpPort { get; set; }
```

And this is the code of NumericBox:

```
<div class="Component-Container-Border" style="@BorderWidth">
<div class="Component-Label" style="@LabelOfComponentWidth">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model)</div>
<div class="Component-Container-ComponentAndValidation" style="float:right;margin-bottom:0px;">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { type = "text", Class = "k-textbox", Value = Value, style = ComponentWidth + ";direction:ltr;border:1px solid #df795a;font-family:MasterFont,tahoma;", MaxLength = Len, Min = MinValue, Max = MaxValue })        
    <script>
        $("#@FieldName").on("keydown",function(e) {OnKeyDownIntegerNumber(e)});
        $("#@FieldName").on("input change keypress",function(e) {
            $(e.target).valid();
        });
    </script>
</div>
<div style="float:right;">
    <input id="ButtonPlus" type="Button" value="+" class="k-button" style="width: 28px; margin: 2px 2px 1px 0px; padding: 0px; height: 26px;font-size: 13px;" onclick="ButtonPlusClick(this, @MaxValue)" />
</div>
@if (Unit.Trim() != "")
{
    <div style="float:right;">
        <input id="ButtonMinus" type="Button" value="-" class="k-button" style="width: 28px; margin: 2px 2px 1px 0px; padding: 0px; height: 26px; font-size: 13px;" onclick="ButtonMinusClick(this, @MinValue)" />
    </div>
    <span style="float:right;margin-right:5px;margin-top:5px;">@Unit</span>
}
else
{
    <div>
        <input id="ButtonMinus" type="Button" value="-" class="k-button" style="width: 28px; margin: 2px 2px 1px 0px; padding: 0px; height: 26px; font-size: 13px;" onclick="ButtonMinusClick(this, @MinValue)" />
    </div>
}
<div style="height:19px;">
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model, "", new { @class = "Component-Validation-Message"})
</div>
```

But when I input a number that is out of range, validation shows me the default range message instead of my custom message.

Like This:
[Showing default message of range validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTL4C.png)

This is inspect of My textBox and javascript files
[inspect and javascripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyton.png)

So, where I could be wrong, since the messages are not showing correctly?

Comment: Is unobtrusive validation enabled for the project? If so you may need to extend the jQuery validate plugin, also can you provide a picture of a browser inspect of the element with the generated data attributes for it.

Comment: Thank you for your consideration but other validations such as required or StringLength work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out my problem, it was referred to this line:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { type = "text", Class = "k-textbox", Value = Value, style = ComponentWidth + ";direction:ltr;border:1px solid #df795a;font-family:MasterFont,tahoma;", MaxLength = Len, Min = MinValue, Max = MaxValue })
```

When I use min and max attribute, range validator just shoes default message and I changed to this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { type = "text", Class = "k-textbox", Value = Value, style = ComponentWidth + ";direction:ltr;border:1px solid #df795a;font-family:MasterFont,tahoma;", MaxLength = Len})
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where data validation in MVC for a dropdown simply did not work.

```
[Required]
public int? intEquipmentModelID { get; set; }
public SelectList? EquipmentDescriptionList { get; set; }
```

I was able to 'trick' the system into realizing it was missing by using the Range option.

```
[Required]
[Range(1, 2000000, ErrorMessage = "Equipment missing.")]
public int? intEquipmentModelID { get; set; }
public SelectList? EquipmentDescriptionList { get; set; }
```

Most dropdowns have an integer Id that is non-zero. Requiring it to be greater than zero does the trick if Select One is associated with zero (0). If the dropdown is a text value, then disallowing blank or disallowing 'Select One' SHOULD theoretically also do the trick, although I have never tried or tested that.